# sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly analyze multiples assembly in sonarqube 5.1/ or in TC sonarqube runner

Tags: c#, sonarqube, teamcity

i have SonarQube 5.1 and i need to use FxCop rules but when i add the Parameter the sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly in TeamCity SonarQube runner it return errors

"The property "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly" must be set and the project must have been built to execute FxCop rules....etc..."

So we try to manually added the single assembly in Deprecated TAB in SonarQube sites(localhost:9000) and it works but we have multiple assembly that need to analyze so our question now is how to anaylze multiple assemly in sonarqube 5.1 is there someone know how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the MSBuild SonarQube Runner to analyze your C# project as documented on http://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/csharp.html

The MSBuild SonarQube Runner has been developed jointly with Microsoft, and fully integrates with MSBuild, solving many of the integration issues we were previously facing with the C# plugin. For example, FxCop now gets executed during the build by MSBuild, with all the right parameters.

You shouldn't have to manually set the `sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly` property, nor any of the other properties listed under the `Deprecated` tab.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the commands from a "Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2013 or higher" (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) in order for the variables to be set.

Answer (score 0):

I have just done a fresh install of 
- SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 4.2.0.1214 
- Visual Studio Community 2015

and I am getting "The property "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly" must be set and the project either running from windows cmd line or running from a developper command prompt

the sonarQube server is Version 5.6.2